# jQuery Ajax Response works only once until page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is simple subscriber form submit with jQuery Ajax, everything is working fine but alert response show only one time until page refresh.

Here is my view code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#ssubmit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    let subscriber = $("#subscriber").val()
    subscriberdata = {subscriber: subscriber,}
  
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "form-process.php",
      data: JSON.stringify(subscriberdata),
      success: function (response) {
        subscribersucess = "<div class='alert alert-success text-center mt-3'>" + response + "</div>";
        $("#alerts").html(subscribersucess);
  
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('#alerts').fadeOut("slow");
        },5000)
  
        $("#subscriberform")[0].reset();
      }
    });
  
  })
});
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using fadeout function. Once fadeout happens display becomes none. And it will only works when you refresh the page.

You can use below code

```
let subscriber = $("#subscriber").val()

subscriberdata = {subscriber: subscriber,}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "form-process.php",
  data: JSON.stringify(subscriberdata),
  success: function (response) {

    subscribersucess = "<div class='alert alert-success text-center mt-3'>" + response + "</div>";
    $('#alerts').show().html();
                $("#alerts").html(subscribersucess);    
                    $('#alerts').delay(5000).fadeOut(); 
    


    $("#subscriberform")[0].reset();

  }

});
```